# Are the HTTP Connection header values case sensitive?

Tags: http, http-headers

Are **values** such as `keep-alive`, `Close`, and `Upgrade` of the `Connection:` header case sensitive?

I'm writing a simple web server and wondering whether I should be transforming the values to lower case before checking them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can’t find any explicit specification of the case-sensitivity of the *Connection*’s field values. But as [*Connection* may contain the name of header fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10):

> […] for each connection-token in this field,
> remove any header field(s) from the message with the same name as the
> connection-token.

and as those [header field names are case-insensitive](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2), I conclude that the *Connection*’s field value is also considered case-insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

No, the Connection header values (a.k.a. "connection options") are case-insensitive.  The [updated HTTP 1.1 RFC 7230, in section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.1) states:

> The Connection header field's value has the following grammar:
>
> ```
> Connection        = 1#connection-option
> connection-option = token
> ```
>
> **Connection options are case-insensitive.**

My bold.  Note that all [header fields](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) are case-insensitive.

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name...

Of course, keep in mind that this is just what the specification says. It doesn't mean that all browser, server, etc. implementations are compliant (or bug-free ;)

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the source code of Chromium and observed that the values of the **X-Frame-Options** header are also case-insensitive. Here is the related part of the code: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/02e65feb53029473f796c1bc2bbbf214ea627688/services/network/public/cpp/x_frame_options_parser.cc#L30

[image]

Just for your information, dear StackOverflow users.